# "Responsive" buttons with ::before and ::after shape

Tags: html, css

By responsive I mean that they still look good with slightly longer text and don't have fixed width.

I am trying to make buttons that look exactly like in image below, but I can't get them to be the right width. I thought adding padding on left and right side would do it, but that doesn't work with the "ADD" button. My task is to convert a .psd to html/css pixel perfect which is kind of dumb and results in bad code.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emils/9g7cn7eh/

Buttons:

[image]

Button:

```
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="action-btn" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
.btn-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.action-btn {
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 20px;
    color: #f5f8f9;
    font-size: 0.9375em;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #aecacc;
    border: 0;
}
.action-btn:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-top: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.action-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #aecacc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the buttons, and use `right`/`left` to move the pseudo elements.
JSfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9g7cn7eh/2/)

```css
.btn-container {
 position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.action-btn {
 padding: 4px 9px 4px 20px;
 color: #f5f8f9;
 font-size: 0.9375em;
 letter-spacing: 0.4px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #aecacc;
 border: 0;
  position: relative; /* we need this for the pseudo elements positioning */
}
.action-btn:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 top: 0;
  left: 0;
 /*margin-left: -20px;*/
 border-top: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
 border-left: 7px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.action-btn:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 top: 0;
  right: -15px;
 /*margin-left: 8px;*/
 border-top: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
 border-left: 15px solid #aecacc;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="action-btn" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="action-btn" type="submit">View Basket</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="action-btn" type="submit">View All (15)</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="action-btn" type="submit">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, `position: relative` helped to keep it all together. Is it possible to make all buttons look like in image without each of them having their own CSS styling?

Comment: All the buttons have the same CSS. What are you talking about?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out. I was talking about making buttons to look exactly like in image above without styling them individually (padding). I just had to set a min-width to the button.